# Store a bigger string to an arr[num]

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I saw this question in an online C test

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main()
{ 
 char arr[11]="The African Queen"; 
 printf("%s",arr); 

 return 0; 
}
```

> What will print:
>  a The African Queen 
>  b The
>  c The
>   African
>  d Compilation error **<-this is the answer due to the site**

However I run it because I answered the C and I just got a warning `warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long` and it printed the C! Is it because I used a different compiler? Or the answer is just wrong?

Comment: e. `arr[10]` is `'n'` arr not terminate by '\0'.

Comment: Probably display "The African" and then Access to outside the bounds of the array occurs. (UB) (1)normal end. (2) display garbage (3) Memory access violation occurs. (4) etc.

Comment: _initializer-string for array of chars is too long_ is not error in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on compiler.

`gcc` gives `warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long [enabled by default]`
and print `The African`.

`Turbo c++` on windows will give compiler error `Too many initializers`

And one thing @BLUEPIXY said ***e. arr[10] is 'n' arr not terminate by '\0'.***